# No callback passed to the ApiClient

Tags: javascript, api, facebook-opengraph

When I try to perform an action with JS `FB.api([...]`, I get `No callback passed to the ApiClient [...]`
Where can I set this callback?

Comment: The 'ApiClient'? Aren't the callbacks usually defined directly in your call to FB.api() or FB.ui()

Comment: ok, got it. I just had to add a function in the `FB.api()`call

Comment: You should probably add that as the answer and accept it, then

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add a callback function to the API call:

```
    FB.api(
        '/me/[YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE]:[YOUR_ACTION]',
        'post',
        { recipe: '[LINK_TO_YOUR_OBJECT]' },
        function(response) {
            if (!response || response.error) {
                alert('Error occured');
            } 
            else {
                alert('Action was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id)
            }
         }
    );
```